# Siebel testing with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, sessionid, siebel

I am currently working on testing (Jmeter) and I wanted to test the Siebel work load structure with Jmeter. For first time I am able to store the session and when I run the same test plan its gives error so to clear that error and run the test I need session id and I was not able to find session id. Could any one suggest me where can I find the session id of siebel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying to test regular user interface? Siebel GUI stores session id in cookies - so you have to enable support for cookies in JMeter.
This is taken from JMeter wiki:

> To add cookie support, simply add an HTTP Cookie Manager to each Thread Group in your test plan. This will ensure that each thread gets its own cookies, but shared across all HTTP Request objects.
>
> To add the HTTP Cookie Manager , simply select the Thread Group , and choose Add --> Config Element --> HTTP Cookie Manager, either from the Edit Menu, or from the right-click pop-up menu.

Hope this helps :)